# Stray cats under the deck

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, strays

So we recently found out that we have a problem. We have a little group of cats in our neighborhood and they have settled themselves in under our deck. There are three cats and they won't leave from under our deck and my cats don't like going outside anymore.

We used to leave the food outside for my two cats because they used to wander all day, but now we keep it inside because of the strays. Still, even now they won't leave.

*They are fed by the neighbors down the street, so I know they aren't starving.*

Does anyone know how to get rid of them, so my cats would go outside again?

Comment: You could catch them in a humane trap and take them to a shelter.

Comment: I dont know if somoene owns them because i constantly see them at one persons house if they arent under my deck

Answer (score 5):

Install some screening or lattice below your deck to prevent them from going underneath. They will probably move on to other places if your food source is gone.

Answer (score 2):

**To lure out female cats, play crying kitten sounds.**

Females, even if they are spayed are very receptive to the crying kittens. They will move out to check out the kittens so you can trap them, of course humanely or scare them.

**To lure out male cats, play fighting cat sounds.**

Males, even if they are afraid, usually check out other fighting males to judge if they are safe. If they are brave, they will try to find and engage those fighting males. Then you can trap them, of course humanely or scare them.

If you play fighting cat sounds a lot, and if you remove their food incentive, they will eventually deem that your house is not worth the risk of engaging in a cat fight.

Also, make changes in the deck to prevent them from getting in once they move out.